# Best Approach for sending message

Tags: .net, .net-4.0, messaging, remote-server

I have a client(machine 1) and server (machine 2). Base on some event occurrence the server needs to send a message to client which the client will show on screen (can be a winforms form). Am want the solution to be in .Net 4.0.

What should be the best approach to be taken in this.

Comment: are there any restrictions (physical), because there are many ways to do it. I would take a look at a ServiceBus example, There are some good examples coming with [NServiceBus download](http://nservicebus.com/) or [MassTransit](http://code.google.com/p/masstransit/) that seem to match exactly your requirements.

Comment: My client and server both will be in same office. Only part is that I will have many client and only one server. The server will have the client IP and send the message to be displayed on the client.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is a "real" answer - maybe it's just a tip and it requires furhter reading, but it may be helpful:

Sounds as if a **ServiceBus** would be a good choice.
There are many ServiceBus implementations ([NServicebus](http://nservicebus.com/), [MassTransit](http://code.google.com/p/masstransit/), [Rhino Servicebus](http://hibernatingrhinos.com/open-source/rhino-service-bus),...). I have to mention that you need some learning how a Servicebus works (what are the different options etc.). A Servicebus usually uses an underlying queue mechanism (MSMQ, ZeroMQ etc) to store the messages/deliver them.

They support different communication types (publish-subscribe etc.). A Servicebus handles all message delivering for you (I see a Servicebus as an infrastructure to send/receive messages), so you just send a message and the servicebus will make sure it get's delivered (depending on the configuration). Usually a servicebus also handles retries (could not process message), timeouts etc.

Due to the fact that there are a lot of options and different scenarios that a servicebus supports, I suggest you to read some examples. Since your scenario sounds like a publish-subscribe scenario (I may be wrong) - where you clients subscribe for messages send by the server. - try to read the examples from one of the mentioned ServiceBus implementations [Masstransit example](https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/tree/master/src/Samples/PublishSubscribe)
. Usually all of the 3 servicebuses have some good example applications with them.

Hope that helps and good luck.